# how to test RMI program in java

Tags: java, rmi

As I'm trying to achieve my first RMI program, I'm having troubles testing it.

I compiled my programs and tried to launch my server but an error then occurs.

About my server: 1 interface + 1 class implementing it + my server class

- Interface

  ```
  package src;
  import java.rmi.*;
  public interface Information extends Remote {

  // methods than can be called remotly

  public String getInformation() throws RemoteException;

  }
  ```
- Class Implementing it

  ```
  package src;
  import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
  import java.rmi.RemoteException;

  public class InformationImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Information {

  protected InformationImpl() throws RemoteException {
      super();
  }

  public String getInformation() throws RemoteException {
      System.out.println("method getInformation()");
      return "hello";
  }
  }
  ```
- My server class :

  ```
  package src;

  import java.net.InetAddress;
  import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.net.UnknownHostException;
  import java.rmi.Naming;
  import java.rmi.RemoteException;
  import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

  public class LanceServeur {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
       LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
       InformationImpl informationImpl = new InformationImpl();
       Naming.rebind("MyServer", informationImpl);
       System.out.println("Server launched");
     } 

     catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  ```
- And my client class :

  ```
   package src;

  import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.rmi.Naming;
  import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
  import java.rmi.Remote;
  import java.rmi.RemoteException;

  public class lanceClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Lancement du client");
     try {
       Remote r = Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/TestRMI");
       System.out.println(r);
       if (r instanceof Information) {
          String s = ((Information) r).getInformation();
          System.out.println("chaine renvoyee = " + s);
       }
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (RemoteException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (NotBoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
     System.out.println("end of client");
    }
   }
  ```

If you want to see the correct lines, check my github it's easier :
https://github.com/TLprojet/MUD_Java

About the error, here it is:

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 0.0.21.214; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:631)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:209)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:338)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:147)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at src.LanceServeur.main(LanceServeur.java:16)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:540)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:436)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:213)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Give us a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not a github link. If it's very short it shouldn't be hard to post here.

Comment: LanceServeur.java:16 is a `println`. Runned code and github sources are differents

Comment: this error refers to the         LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

Comment: @jhamon I modified my post and the error, it now fits the github code.

Comment: As it's written, port 1099 is already in use by another process. Maybe one other instance of your program, or an unrelated program

Comment: I've launched it all back and now an other error appears : I modified my post so you can see the new one. It is the one I have since yesterday and I can't  fix it

Comment: You have a port already in use, as mentioned by others.  You also are binding your object as "MyServer", but you are looking it up with "TestRMI" which doesn't match the name of the object binding.

Comment: Thanx for your answer about the names I modified it. As for the port already in use, just actualize this page because this error doesn't appear anymore, an other one is.

Comment: Another error such as what?